# Setting NameSpace while storing from Spark to HBase using saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataSet

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, cloudera

I am trying to save data from Spark into HBase using saveHadoopDataSet API . Please refer the below code . Code is working fine .But the table is getting stored in the default namespace.How can I set the namespace in the below code, so that the table get stored in the desired namespace instead of default.

```
wordCounts.foreachRDD ( rdd => {
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, "stream_count")
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost:2181")
conf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60000");
conf.set("hbase.rootdir", "file:///tmp/hbase")

val jobConf = new Configuration(conf)
jobConf.set("mapreduce.job.output.key.class", classOf[Text].getName)
jobConf.set("mapreduce.job.output.value.class", classOf[LongWritable].getName)
jobConf.set("mapreduce.outputformat.class", classOf[TableOutputFormat[Text]].getName)

rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(jobConf)   })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from mailing list .

```
Replace <output_table_name> with "<namespace>:<output_table_name>"
```